# Computing greatest common denominator in python

Tags: python, division, integer

If you have a list of integers in python, say `L = [4,8,12,24]`, how can you compute their greatest common denominator/divisor (4 in this case)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

One way to do it is:

```
import fractions

def gcd(L):
    return reduce(fractions.gcd, L)

print gcd([4,8,12,24])
```

Comment: Great example for getting short code with python. I was searching exactly for *that* kind of solution.

Comment: This is correct only for Python 2.X. For Python 3.X see answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61779475/4769067