# Efficient way of computing the Greatest Common Divisor from an Array - Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, greatest-common-divisor

I have created the following function, which takes two `Integers` as parameters and computes the GCD of them:

```
func getGCD(_ num1: Int, _ num2: Int) -> Int {

    let remainder = num1 % num2
    if remainder != 0 {
        return gcd(num2, remainder)
    } else {
        return num2
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** I want to use `Recursivity`.

**Question 1:** Is there any way to make this function more efficient?

**Question 2:** How can I use this function for an `Array` of type `[Int]`?

Comment: This place is not meant to give you  a solution to your homework

Comment: This is just an algorithm question. Language is effectively irrelevant. Good discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16628088/euclidean-algorithm-gcd-with-multiple-numbers

Comment: Your code doesn't work anyway, because `getGCD` and `gcd` are two different names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have a function `gcd` (or `getGCD`) working for two integers, the following will work for an array `arr` of integers:

```
let result = arr.reduce(0) {gcd($0,$1)}
```

Comment: So does mine, actually. The problem lies in your `getGCD`, which is totally broken in the form you have shown it in any case.

Comment: oh, yes sorry. It is my fault.

Comment: No, now that I have read both the answers twice, it is clear that your answer is better,  because it is very efficient compared to the other one, and my function was messed up, anyways. Thanks for your time!

Comment: you could even write `arr.reduce(0, gcd)`

Comment: @ramzesenok nice one!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your function doesn't work for negative `Integers`, so a way to make it "more efficient" is to use `abs()`, to get the absolute value of the numbers:

```
func gcd(_ a: Int, _ b: Int) -> Int {
    let remainder = abs(a) % abs(b)
    if remainder != 0 {
        return gcd(abs(b), remainder)
    } else {
        return abs(b)
    }
}
```

Second Question - Working with arrays:

```
var numbers = [5,10]
var index = 0
var result = 0
if numbers.isEmpty{result=0}
else if numbers.count == 1{result = numbers[0]}
else{
    while index <= numbers.count-1{
        if index==0{
            result = gcd(numbers[index], numbers[index + 1])
            index+=2
        }
        else {
            result = gcd(result,numbers[index])
            index+=1
        }
    }

}
print(result) // prints 5
```

Comment: Thank you for suggesting the function improvement! However, I have accepted Matt's answer since it is way more efficient