# Python gcd for list

Tags: python, algorithm, greatest-common-divisor

I want to calculate gcd for a list of numbers.
But I don't know what's wrong with my code.

```
A = [12, 24, 27, 30, 36]


def Greatest_Common_Divisor(A):
    for c in A:
        while int(c) > 0:
            if int(c) > 12:
                c = int(c) % 12
            else:
                return 12 % int(c)
    print Greatest_Common_Divisor(A)
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175131/code-for-greatest-common-divisor-in-python) shows that it's already implemented in the standard library. Just use `from fractions import gcd`.

Comment: Also, as soon as that `return 12 % int(c)` statement executes, the function ends. Did you mean to perhaps be using [generators](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/04/07/improve-your-python-yield-and-generators-explained/)?

Answer (score 36):

As of python 3.9, python got built-in support for calculating gcd over a list of numbers.

```
import math
A = [12, 24, 27, 30, 36]
print(math.gcd(*A))
```

Output:

```
3
```

Answer (score 35):

here is the piece of code, that I used:

```
from fractions import gcd
from functools import reduce
def find_gcd(list):
    x = reduce(gcd, list)
    return x
```

Comment: I got a warning that fractions.gcd is deprecated. Using math.gcd is now recommended.

Comment: `from math import gcd` at python 3.

Answer (score 12):

```
def gcd (a,b):
    if (b == 0):
        return a
    else:
         return gcd (b, a % b)
A = [12, 24, 27, 30, 36]
res = A[0]
for c in A[1::]:
    res = gcd(res , c)
print res
```

[ideone link](https://ideone.com/MFJESY)

Answer (score 5):

I used this piece of code:

```
def gcd(my_list):
    result = my_list[0]
    for x in my_list[1:]:
        if result < x:
            temp = result
            result = x
            x = temp
        while x != 0:
            temp = x
            x = result % x
            result = temp
    return result
```

Answer (score 5):

If you'd like to use an existing method try [`np.gcd.reduce'](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.gcd.html?highlight=gcd#numpy.gcd):

```
import numpy as np

A = [12, 24, 27, 30, 36]

print(np.gcd.reduce(A))
```

which returns `3`

Comment: Its giving WA on list len > 100000

Comment: @DikShU Tell us more! This works for me with a length of 1,000,000 `np.gcd.reduce((6060842*np.random.rint(1, 10000000, 1000000)).tolist())` returns `6060842` using numpy 1.19.2 What exactly is the test for which it is failing for you? What version of numpy are you using? What other gcd methods are passing your test that this fails?

Comment: I am using this on Codechef(CP site in India) where it is passing tests cases where length is < 1000 but further on Original Constraints it is Giving WA.

Comment: @DikShU I see, "WA" = Wrong Answer. I went to the site and tried to run it https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iHu7.png and I couldn't import `numpy` https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mi4fu.png so I couldn't even test it there. I'm not sure how Python runs on the site, but this method seems fine when running locally on a computer. I don't know exactly why you get "WA" but that seems to be related to Codechef, it's not a Python message. By the way, my original is a typo, it's `np.random.randint` not `...rint`

Comment: for running python on Codechef run code under try and except and thx for help ... it may be some other Reason for WA .further the question here ---"https://www.codechef.com/JULY21C/problems/MINNOTES"

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear to me why you are using 12 in your function? Do you want to test your algorithm with 12 specifically?

There is built in function that provides a good solution (`fraction.gcd()`) as referenced in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640955/computing-greatest-common-denominator-in-python)

If you want to develop your own approach, you could do it this way: sort the list and get the minimum number of list (call it `min`).  Loop from 2 to `min`, you can get the great common divisor of your list.

Answer (score 3):

```
import functools as f
A = [12, 24, 27, 30, 36]
g = lambda a,b:a if b==0 else g(b,a%b)   #Gcd for two numbers
print(f.reduce(lambda x,y:g(x,y),A))     #Calling gcd function throughout the list.
```

"Lambda" is an anonymous function where 'g' is assigned with GCD of two numbers whenever called.

"Reduce" is a function in "functools" module which is used to perform a particular function to all of the elements in the list.
Here reduce() computes the GCD of the complete list A by computing GCD of first two elements, then the GCD of 3rd element with previously computed GCD of first two elements and so on.

Hope this clears your doubt.

Comment: From review: could you please add more explanation as for why this solves the problem?

Comment: Hey, yes I have added more explanation on how this solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`return` exits the function. Inside a for-loop this is normally not intended.

Answer (score 1):

As I see your code will simply go in infinite loop. Since you call method Greatest_Common_Divisor recursively but without base case. Align 
print Greatest_Common_Divisor(A)  and "def" in the same column and that problem would be solved. But still what your code does for each number ai, it takes remainder of ai % 12, and then simply print 12 % (ai % 12), and there is no any connection between it and greatestCommonDivisor. 
Here is simple code for gcd(a,b) which you can use for the whole array:

```
def gcd (a,b):
    if (b == 0):
        return a
    else:
         return gcd (b, a % b)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from functools import reduce
def gcd(a,b):
    if a==0:
        return b 
    else:
        return gcd(b%a,a)
A = [12, 24, 27, 30, 36]
gcdp = reduce(lambda x,y:gcd(x,y),A)
print(gcdp)
```

I guess this one will clear your doubts.

Answer (score 1):

gcd of a list input by the user which can be used for any number of input values.

```
 n = int(input('enter no of numbers: '))
a = list(map(int,input('enter numbers to find gcd: ').strip().split()))[:n]

def gcd(num1,num2):
    x = 1
    while x:
        if max(num1,num2) % min(num1,num2) == 0:
            return min(num1,num2)
            x = 0
        else :
            r = max(num1,num2)%min(num1,num2)
            return gcd(max(num1,num2),r)

while True:
        a[0] = gcd(a[0],a[1])
        a.pop(1)
        if len(set(a))>2:
            a.pop(2)
        if len(set(a)) == 1:
            break
a = set(a)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def find_gcd(l):
    def gcd(a, b):
        while b:
            a, b = b, a%b
        return a
    n =1
    f = l[0]
    while n != len(l):
        f = gcd(f,l[n])
        if  f == 1:
            return 1
        else:
            n = n + 1          
    return f

l = [12, 24, 27, 30, 36]
print(find_gcd(l))
```